# html: overflow issue on mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with parallax effect on mobile. In fact it seems like that total body size is > 100vh (it also appear the scroll bar o the side). Obv if I change overflow-y from auto to hidden, it fix the problem but it also cut out part of the page. On desktop it doesn't happen. Can anybody help me?

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/unhXH.jpg

```css
.selector-for-some-widget {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

header .carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: calc(100% - 75px);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
}

.background {
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2.5);
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Montez', cursive;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  background-color: white;
}

.navbar {
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Bootstrap Icon CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <!-- Style CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <title>Ariano Francesco Photography</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide background" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('img/carousel_1.jpg')">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('img/carousel_2.jpg')">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
        data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
        data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Ariano Francesco</h1>
        <h2>Photography</h2>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white sticky-top shadow-sm">
        <div class="container px-5">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AFR</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar"
            aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar"
            aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
            <div class="offcanvas-header justify-content-end">
              <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"
                aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="offcanvas-body d-flex text-center align-items-center">
              <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item ms-2">
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ms-2">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container px-5">
        <div class="text-center mt-5">
          <h2 class="fw-bold fade-in">Gallery</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-5">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
            <a href="img/_IMG1556.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="fade-in">
              <img src="img/_IMG1556.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded mb-4">
            </a>
            <a href="img/_IMG1594.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="fade-in">
              <img src="img/_IMG1594.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded mb-4">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="img/_IMG1491.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="fade-in">
              <img src="img/_IMG1491.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded mb-4">
            </a>
            <a href="img/_IMG1558.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="fade-in">
              <img src="img/_IMG1558.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded mb-4">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="img/_IMG74c91.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="fade-in">
              <img src="img/_IMG74c91.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded mb-4">
            </a>
            <a href="img/_IMG1510.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="fade-in">
              <img src="img/_IMG1510.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded mb-4">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="text-center text-muted">
        <div class="container px-5">
          <div class="mb-4 border-bottom">
            <a class="btn btn-floating m-3" href="https://instagram.com/_afr.photo" role="button"><i
                class="bi bi-facebook"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-floating m-3" href="https://www.facebook.com/ArianoFrancescoPH" role="button"><i
                class="bi bi-instagram"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-4">
            <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4">
              Contact
            </h6>
            <p>
              Castagnole delle Lanze, AT
            </p>
            <p>
              franci.ariano@gmail.com
            </p>
            <p>
              339 2350792
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-4" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);">
          © 2022 Copyright:
          <a class="text-reset fw-bold" href="www.afr.altervista.org">Ariano Francesco Photography</a>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </section>
  </div>
  <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Lightbox for Bootstrap 5 -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bs5-lightbox@1.7.11/dist/index.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Script.js -->
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the issue, You need to attach screenshot also

Comment: It seems like your snipped is not having the issue. Anyway, what I usually do to fix this is wrap the whole page in a new <div> and set overflow: hidden to that one

Comment: @Priya jain https://imgur.com/a/n9wMmqN this is it. The first one happen when you scroll down normally. Then sometimes scroll bar paper for showing more. I've also uploaded it there, if u want to take a look https://afr.altervista.org

Comment: @Arianoxx This is working fine. Your snipped and screenshot have not issue. If still you are facing then please mark issue on screenshot.

Comment: @Priya jain yep, from pc it's working just fine, but try it with a phone, and u are going to notice that at first you can't see the Navbar like on pc, and then at the end of the page, part of the footer is hidden, and you need to scroll down. Is like that all the body is -75px from the top, but it happen just with mobile device. Here there is also a video that is showing it a little better: https://imgur.com/a/LhHQyCE

Answer (score 1):

Look at this answer: https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/

[image]

```js
// First we get the viewport height and we multiple it by 1% to get a value for a vh unit
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
// Then we set the value in the --vh custom property to the root of the document
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.module {
  height: 100vh; /* Use vh as a fallback for browsers that do not support Custom Properties */
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.module__item {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 20%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.module__item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #F73859;
}

.module__item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F73859;
  color: #F1D08A;
}
```

```html
<div class="module">
  <div class="module__item">20%</div>
  <div class="module__item">40%</div>
  <div class="module__item">60%</div>
  <div class="module__item">80%</div>
  <div class="module__item">100%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fix 100vh Issue on Mobile Devices Using CSS Only**

Sometimes, the purpose of using vh unit is to simply create sections equal to the height of the viewport. This is common when you are building landing pages, for instance. In these situations, position sticky won’t help and I want to introduce the fill-available property. It’s easy to use, just remember to use the prefixes and the fall-back value:

```
.layout {
  min-height: 100vh;            /* fall-back */
  min-height: -moz-available;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
  min-height: fill-available;
}
```

Just as simple as that!